# How to run a .group() with Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this query in mongoDB and that produces the result that I want. But now I'm trying to use that in java.

This is the query in MongoDB:

```
var red = function(doc, out) {
out.count_order++;
out.sum_qty += doc.quantity;
out.sum_base_price += doc.extendedprice;
out.sum_disc_price += doc.extendedprice * (1 - doc.discount);
out.sum_charge += doc.extendedprice * (1 - doc.discount) * (1 + doc.tax);
out.avg_disc += doc.discount;
};

var avg = function(out) {
out.avg_qty = out.sum_qty / out.count_order;
out.avg_price = out.sum_base_price / out.count_order;
out.avg_disc = out.avg_disc / out.count_order;
};

db.lineitems.group( {
key : { returnflag : true, linestatus : true},
cond : { "shipdate" : {$lte: 19980801}},
initial: { count_order : 0, sum_qty : 0, sum_base_price : 0, sum_disc_price : 0,
sum_charge : 0, avg_disc : 0},
reduce : red,
finalize : avg
});
```

And now the way I'm using it in Java but I don't know how to use the **avg** function.

```
    String avg = "var avg = function(out) {"
            + "out.avg_qty = out.sum_qty / out.count_order;"
            + "out.avg_price = out.sum_base_price / out.count_order;"
            + "out.avg_disc = out.avg_disc / out.count_order;};";

    String reduce = "function(doc, out) {"
            + "out.count_order++;"
            + "out.sum_qty += doc.quantity;"
            + "out.sum_base_price += doc.extendedprice;"
            + "out.sum_disc_price += doc.extendedprice * (1 - doc.discount);"
            + "out.sum_charge += doc.extendedprice * (1 - doc.discount) * (1 + doc.tax);"
            + "out.avg_disc += doc.discount;};";

    String finalize = "function(out) {"
            + "out.avg_qty = out.sum_qty / out.count_order;"
            + "out.avg_price = out.sum_base_price / out.count_order;"
            + "out.avg_disc = out.avg_disc / out.count_order;};";

    MapReduceIterable<Document> iterable = collection.mapReduce(**????**, reduce).finalizeFunction(finalize);
```

How can I use that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off using the aggreation framework for this than calling the [`.group()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) method, which is of course an older implementation before the aggregation framework actually existed.

The logic as applied in the shell would be:

```js
db.lineitems.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "shipdate": { "$lte": 19980801 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "returnflag": "$returnflag",
            "linestatus": "$linestatus"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 },
        "sum_qty": { "$sum": "$quantity" },
        "avg_qty": { "$avg": "$quantity" },
        "sum_base_price": { "$sum": "$extendedprice" },
        "avg_base_price": { "$avg": "$extendedprice" },
        "sum_disc_price": {
            "$sum": {
                "$multiply": [
                    "$extendedprice",
                    { "$subtract": [ 1, "$discount" ] }
                ]
            }
        },
        "avg_disc_price": {
            "$avg": {
                "$multiply": [
                    "$extendedprice",
                    { "$subtract": [ 1, "$discount" ] }
                ]
            }
        },
        "sum_charge": {
            "$sum": {
                "$multiply": [
                    "$extendedprice",
                    { "$subtract": [ 1, "$discount" ] },
                    { "$add": [ 1, "$tax" ] }
                ]
            }
        },
        "avg_disc": { "$avg": "$discount" }
    }}
])
```

The aggregation framework as a very efficient [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage operator which does all the same things in native coded operations. There is [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) and [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) accumulators built in as well as the other math operations.

In short, as "natively coded" and not relying on "JavaScript interpretation", the execution is much faster than what `.group()` can provide. Plus it really should be fairly straightforward to understand.

Translating that to Java would be something like

```java
List<Document> pipeline = Arrays.<Document>asList(
  new Document(
    "$match", new Document(
      "shipdate", new Document(
        "$lte", 19980801             
      )
    )
  ),
  new Document(
    "$group", new Document(
      "_id", new Document(
        "returnflag", "$returnflag"
      ).append( "linestatus", "$linestatus" )
    ).append(
      "count", new Document( "$sum", 1 )
    ).append(
      "sum_qty", new Document( "$sum", "$quantity" )
    ).append(
      "avg_qty", new Document( "$avg", "$quantity" )
    ).append(
      "sum_base_price", new Document( "$sum", "$extendedprice" )
    ).append(
      "avg_base_price", new Document( "$avg", "$extendedprice" )
    ).append(
      "sum_disc_price", new Document(
        "$sum", new Document(
          "$multiply", Arrays.asList(
            "$extendedprice",
            new Document(
              "$subtract", Arrays.asList(1, "$discount")
            )
          )
        )
      )
    ).append(
      "avg_disc_price", new Document(
        "$avg", new Document(
          "$multiply", Arrays.asList(
            "$extendedprice",
            new Document(
              "$subtract", Arrays.asList(1, "$discount")
            )
          )
        )
      )
    ).append(
      "sum_charge", new Document(
        "$sum", new Document(
          "$multiply", Arrays.asList(
            "$extendedprice",
            new Document(
              "$subtract", Arrays.asList(1, "$discount")
            ),
            new Document(
              "$add", Arrays.asList(1, "$tax")
            )
          )
        )
      )
    ).append(
      "avg_disc", new Document( "$avg", "$discount" )
    )
  )
);

AggregateIterable<Document> result = collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: I know but I have a solution using the aggregation framework and I need the same result with map reduce to compare... I need to use Java to call both cases.

Comment: @duknust Why do you think you need mapReduce? The explanation here shows you that not only is it "easier" using `.aggregate()` it is actually **far** more performant. It is not possible for mapReduce to compete on performance or scale with `.aggregate()`. And you got the Java code as well. Your comment suggests you have not fully read the answer. I suggest that you do, and learn it's lessons.

Comment: @duknust Of course the other thing here is that your coded functions as well as what you tried in the shell are for the [`.group()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/) method as mentioned. So even the JavaScript code would need considerable alteration to fit `mapReduce` from what you have coded already. So you would either call `.group()` in Java, or change all of the code for `mapReduce`. But the general summary here is that you should not do this. Use `.aggregate()` as shown. It's far better. This is what you are meant to be learning here.

Comment: I know that but I need to have two queries that gives me the same result. Just to get information about how much energy it spends running. That's why I need more than one option and I already have the `.aggregate()` option.